# Removing extra commas from string in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert data from three different drop downs into my spreadsheet but I am having several difficulties. There are three drop downs called cbo_fac1, cbo_fac2 and cbo_fac3.

---

Here are the use cases:

**Use case 1** - Results in `No preference` being inserted into spreadsheet

```
cbo_fac1 - No preference
cbo_fac2 - No preference 
cbo_fac3 - No preference
```

**Use case 2a** - Results in `value, ,` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value`

```
cbo_fac1 - Value
cbo_fac2 - No preference
cbo_fac3 - No preference
```

**Use case 2b** - Results in `, value,` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value`

```
cbo_fac1 - No preference
cbo_fac2 - Value
cbo_fac3 - No preference
```

**Use case 2c** - Results in `, , value` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value`

```
cbo_fac1 - No preference 
cbo_fac2 - No preference 
cbo_fac3 - Value
```

**Use case 3a** - Results in `value, value,` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value, value`

```
cbo_fac1 - Value
cbo_fac2 - Value 
cbo_fac3 - No preference
```

**Use case 3b** - Results in `, value, value` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value, value`

```
cbo_fac1 - No preference
cbo_fac2 - Value 
cbo_fac3 - Value
```

**Use case 3c** - Results in `value, , value` being inserted into spreadsheet. Should just be `value, value`

```
cbo_fac1 - Value
cbo_fac2 - No preference
cbo_fac3 - Value
```

---

How do I remove the extra commas in *Use cases 2a-3c*?

Here is my code so far:

```
If Me.cbo_fac1 <> "No preference" Then
cbo_fac1Entry = Me.cbo_fac1.Value
Else
cbo_fac1Entry = ""
End If

If Me.cbo_fac2 <> "No preference" Then
cbo_fac2Entry = Me.cbo_fac2.Value
Else
cbo_fac2Entry = ""
End If

If Me.cbo_fac3 <> "No preference" Then
cbo_fac3Entry = Me.cbo_fac3.Value
Else
cbo_fac3Entry = ""
End If

cbo_facEntry = cbo_fac1Entry & ", " & cbo_fac2Entry & ", " & cbo_fac3Entry

If cbo_facEntry = " , ," Then
cbo_facEntry = "No preference"
Else
End If
rng1.Offset(1, 15) = cbo_facEntry
```

---

I've tried inserting this code:

```
if right(cbo_facEntry,1)="," then
   cbo_facEntry= left(len(cbo_facEntry)-1)
end if

if left(cbo_facEntry,1)="," then
   cbo_facEntry= right(len(cbo_facEntry)-1)
end if
```

After:

```
If cbo_facEntry = ",," Then
cbo_facEntry = "No Preference"
Else
End If
```

But it doesn't make much difference, as it doesn't fulfil the requirements of all the use cases and also returns an invalid syntax error message.

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these three lines to your code instead of what you've tried:

```
cbo_facEntry = Replace(cbo_facEntry, ", , ", ", ")
If Left(cbo_facEntry, 1) = "," Then cbo_facEntry = Right(cbo_facEntry, Len(cbo_facEntry) - 2)
If Right(cbo_facEntry, 2) = ", " Then cbo_facEntry = Left(cbo_facEntry, Len(cbo_facEntry) - 2)
```

Comment: Do I put it after the `If cbo_facEntry = ",," Then` segment of code?

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple snippet:

```
Dim a(2) As String
a[0] = cbo_fac1
a[1] = cbo_fac2
a[2] = cbo_fac3

Dim I As Integer, result As String
For I = 0 To UBound(a)
    If a(I) <> "No Preference" Then
        If I = 0 Then
            result = a(I)
        Else
            result = result & "," & a(I)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I have not tested this code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Where should I place this code in the context of what I have already?

Comment: You can use this code instead of your current code (just replace cbo_fac1, cbo_fac2, cbo_fac3 in my code with Me.cbo_fac1, Me.cbo_fac2, Me.cbo_fac3)